# GCP pub/sub ordering pull subscription retry can cause out-of-order?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

In this medium article, https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-pub-sub-ordered-delivery-1e4181f60bc8, it was stated:

> The Cloud Pub/Sub service can’t guarantee the success or latency of the response it sends for a subscriber’s pull request. If a response fails and a subsequent pull request is fulfilled with a response containing subsequent messages for the same ordering key, it is possible those subsequent messages could arrive to the subscriber before the messages in the failed response. It also can’t guarantee that the subsequent pull request comes from the same subscriber.

I would like to check what it means with an example:

Subscriber pulls messages for ordering key "A" and receives batch B1 containing messages M1 and M2. 
The subscriber encounters an error processing M2 and retries the pull request.
Before Pub/Sub sends a new response, it should include all unprocessed messages from the previous failed batch B1 (including M2) in the next response, along with any new messages published for the same ordering key since the failure.
Therefore, the next response (let's call it B2') would contain both M2 from the failed attempt and any new messages for ordering key "A" published after the error.

Is this example understanding correct? How would it be possible those subsequent messages could arrive to the subscriber before the messages in the failed response?

Would really appreciate any clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part is the sentence before what you quote: "The requirement that only one batch of messages can be outstanding at a time is necessary to maintain ordered delivery."

The remainder of the paragraph explains why only one batch of messages can be outstanding per ordering key. In your example, if M1 and M2 were already outstanding, then a subsequent pull request would not receive any more messages for key A. If the messages are acked, nacked, or expired (either due to the time expiring or due to the loss of tracking state for the set of outstanding messages), then a subsequent pull request could get messages for key A, starting with the first message that had not been acked.

Not that a subsequent response is not guaranteed to have all messages available for key A; it is just guaranteed to start with the first unacked message.

Comment: Understood thank you so much! This means in my example, "the next response (let's call it B2') would contain both M2 from the failed attempt and any new messages for ordering key "A" published after the error" is correct.

Comment: Well, there are no guarantees what a pull request will include. It could include no messages. It could include messages for a different key. If M2's ack deadline has expired or it was nacked, then a subsequent pull request for key "A" would include M2 and possibly other messages for key "A" that were published to the service after M2. But there is no guarantee that if other messages were published, they will definitely be in the pull response.

Comment: Can I also check my understanding that for an unordered scenario ( no ordering key usage ) and 1 publisher - 1 subscriber model, we cannot assume that the subscriber will always receive messages in the order of messages published to pub/sub server right? ( assuming the publishing is done sequentially )

Comment: With ordering disabled, there are no ordering guarantees.

Comment: I have another question, if a pull request leads to > 1 messages with the same ordering key within the []received_messages ( eg. in the chronological order of Msg A order key A, Msg B order key A ) , even if we nack msg A, the subscriber can still proceed to process msg B right? and on the next pull request, the GCP pub/sub server will resend msg A,B? does it mean to ensure absolute ordering in the sense where msg B should be processed only after A is processed, the devs are responsible for adding additional logic to ensure it?
does setting maxOutstandingMessages = 1 help to avoid this issue?

Comment: also does this occur on both streaming pull and synchronous pull? If msg B should never be processed before msg A in an ordered configuration, what would you recommend me to do? should I just set maxOutstandingMessages = 1 at all times?

Comment: Yes, correct. If you are using streaming pull via the client libraries, setting maxOutstandingMessages to 1 could help, but it is going to severely limit throughput as it'll only allow one outstanding message across all keys, not per key. Without knowing more details than can be explored via a comment thread on Stack Overflow, it's difficult to give an overall recommendation for your entire use case.